# Is there any message that always comes in between WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTNUP?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to write a text on screen
when my mouse's L-button is pressed(hold), the client area shall display
`L-BUTTON-DOWN`
and when I release it ,the screen should display
`L-Button-UP`

This is what I have done so far (**This is window procedure**)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 HDC         hdc ;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
 RECT        rect ;

 switch (message)
 {
 case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
     PlaySound(TEXT("syscom.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
     return 0;

 case WM_CREATE:
     PlaySound (TEXT ("create.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC) ;
     return 0 ;

 case WM_PAINT:

     hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
     GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
     DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello, Windows 32 API!"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_TOP | DT_RIGHT);
     DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello, Windows 32 API!"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE);  //TOP |    LEFT
     EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

     PlaySound(TEXT("paint.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);

     return 0 ;

 case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

     hdc=GetDC(hwnd);
     TextOut(hdc,50,50,TEXT("L-BUTTON-DOWN"),13);
     ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);

     PlaySound(TEXT("lbdown.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);

     //GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
     //InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, TRUE);

     return 0;

 case WM_LBUTTONUP:

     hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
     TextOut(hdc, 50, 50, TEXT("L-BUTTON-UP"), 11);
     ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

     PlaySound(TEXT("lbup.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);

     GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
     InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, TRUE);

     return 0;

 case WM_DESTROY:
     PlaySound(TEXT("close.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
     PostQuitMessage (0) ;

     return 0 ;
 }

 return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

And This is my window class in WinMain

```
 wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
 wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
 wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
 wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
 wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ; //from WinMain arg
 wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_ASTERISK) ;
 wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
 wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (DKGRAY_BRUSH) ;
 wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
 wndclass.lpszClassName = TEXT("HelloWin!!!") ;
```

The problem I am getting is that
when I L-click on client area, the message displays fine,
`L-BUTTON-DOWN`

but when I release it, the second text overlaps....
`L-BUTTON-UPWN`

That clearly means that I need to repaint the client area before I can process `WM_LBUTTONUP`.

How can I do that ? and,

is there any message between `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` that I can use to make the client area invalid ?

Comment: Why not just draw a white rectangle over the text, or something?

Comment: That is one way out.... but you see, how will I get the correct coordinates?

Comment: You use the same coordinates you would have used in the hypothetical in-between-mouse-messages message. If you don't know the coordinates there, handling this hypothetical messages wouldn't be part of the solution.

Comment: please tell me How can I implement it ?

Comment: You can use `GetTextExtentPoint32` or `DrawText` to calculate the pixel size of a text string.

Comment: `GetTextExtentPoint32` can help me... But I don't think that `DrawText` can help me because it only returns height and not width.

Comment: I totally forgot that..sorry @JonathanPotter

Answer (score 5):

When you repaint the text, you never clear the original text. You need to either expand the `L-BUTTON-UP` message so it's the same physical size (ugly hack) or measure the larger text, and fill that rectangle with the background color before you draw the text.

But that won't solve the other problem, which you'll see if you minimize and restore your window, or cover and uncover your window with another window. That is, if the window gets a `WM_PAINT` your message will disappear entirely, which I don't think is the desired behavior.

Your best bet would be to update your `WM_PAINT` message to draw the mouse status text, then update the `WM_MOUSEDOWN` and `WM_MOUSEUP` message handlers appropriately. In pseudocode:

```
WM_PAINT:
    Draw "Hello, Windows 32 API!"
    Draw Mouse_State
WM_MOUSEDOWN:
    Mouse_State = "L-BUTTON-DOWN"
    InvalidateRect(client_area)
WM_MOUSEUP:
    Mouse_State = "L-BUTTON-UP"
    InvalidateRect(client_area)
```